# sbt: How to write a task that runs testQuick only if test fails?

Tags: scala, sbt

This question is from Martin Grotzke on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/i/web/status/1025766778193031173).

He wants to write a task (or a command, I think) that could:

1. First run `test` and if it fails, follow up with `testOnly`
2. Aggregate across multiple sub-projects in a build

Effectively emulating Bash:

```
$ sbt test || sbt testQuick
```

The motivation is to run a failing test twice to work around flaky tests.

Comment: What are some of the circumstances that I want to run testOnly for failed tests immediately after test?

Comment: Running `testQuick` (not `testOnly`) reruns only the failed tests. In a build with lots of tests, unfortunately a project might have a few flaky tests (tests which could fail or pass for the same configuration), and you might not want to block CI/CD/PR validation because of it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### project/TestExtraShotPlugin.scala

If you want the quick answer you can use the following code to achieve running test twice behavior.

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object TestExtraShotPlugin extends AutoPlugin {
  override def requires = plugins.JvmPlugin
  override def trigger = allRequirements
  object autoImport {
    val testNoFail = taskKey[Unit]("test but don't fail")
  }
  import autoImport._

  override def buildSettings = {
    addCommandAlias("testExtraShot", ";testNoFail;testQuick")
  }

  override def projectSettings = {
    Test / testNoFail := (Test / test).result.value
  }
}
```

If you want to know more, please read on.

#### Error handling

First, we need to stop `test` from halting the task execution. The error handling of tasks are described in [Tasks](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Tasks.html#) page of the documentation. But quick gist is that you call `.result.value`. You can pattern match on that to get the values, but we don't really need it here.

I am using that to define an alternative `test` task called `testNoFail`.

#### Ad-hoc plugin

Next, we want `testNoFail` to work in a multi-project build. One way of injecting settings to all subproject is defining a triggered `AutoPlugin` in `project/*.scala`.

```
  override def requires = plugins.JvmPlugin
  override def trigger = allRequirements
```

#### Command composition

If you want to tell sbt to do something **and then** do something else, probably a natural way is to use commands. This is analogous to humans typing things into to the shell consecutively.

Commands can be composed using semicolon `;`.

```
  override def buildSettings = {
    addCommandAlias("testExtraShot", ";testNoFail;testQuick")
  }
```

This is possible because we can safely run [`testQuick` task](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Testing.html#testQuick) regardless of the previous state of the test.

See also [Sequencing How to](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Howto-Sequencing.html) series for other methods of sequencing things.

#### How to use this

Run:

```
> testExtraShot
```

inside the sbt shell. This will run `testNoFail` and then `testQuick`.

### Appendix: Tackling the conditional continuation

Note that I've circumvented Martin's original specification of "in case of failed tests" by running `testQuick` regardless. It's possible to implement this, but it's a bit more advanced.

#### Monadic continuation

We can define a task that first runs normal `test`, then depending on the returned *result* value, change the continuation of the *next* task. In sbt, this type of monadic continuation can be achieved using a [dynamic task](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Tasks.html#Dynamic+Computations+with).

We normally try to avoid this composition, since it prevents the task engine from parallelizing concurrent tasks, but it's handy when we need if-then-do-something.

#### project/TestExtraShotPlugin.scala alternative version

The following implements an ad-hoc plugin that defines a dynamic task:

```scala
import sbt._
import Keys._

object TestExtraShotPlugin extends AutoPlugin {
  override def requires = plugins.JvmPlugin
  override def trigger = allRequirements
  object autoImport {
    val testExtraShot = taskKey[Unit]("test then testQuick only on failure")
  }
  import autoImport._

  override def projectSettings = {
    testExtraShot := (Def.taskDyn {
      val t = (Test / test).result.value
      if (t.toEither.isLeft) (Test / testQuick).toTask("")
      else
        Def.task {
          val s = streams.value
          s.log.info("ok!")
        }
    }).value
  }
}
```